# json encode missing the comma?

Tags: php, arrays, json

I'm trying to get the correct json output after using php nested array and somehow when I use the json_encode it misses the commas between each key value pair and array of item.

```php
$don_info_arr = array();
$don_info_arr['don_info']= array();
$st_contacts_arr = array();
$st_contacts_arr['st_contacts']= array();

$don_contact_arr = array();
$don_contact_arr['don_contact']= array();
$don_contact_item =array(
   'first_name' => $donor->first_name,
   'last_name'  => $donor->last_name
);
 //correspondence_contact 
$correspondence_contact_arr = array();
$correspondence_contact_arr['correspondence_contact']= array();
$correspondence_contact_item =array(
   'first_name' => $donor->first_name_c,
   'last_name'  => $donor->last_name_c
);

$submission = array(
    "don_info" => array (
    "st_contacts" => array (
    "don_contact" => $don_contact_item, 
    "correspondence_contact" =>$correspondence_contact_item)     
)));
echo json_encode($submission);
```

getting this result now.

```
  {
    "don_info": {
        "st_contacts": {
            "don_contact": {
                "first_name": "Test1"
                "last_name": "Test1"
            }
            "correspondence_contact": {
                "first_name": "ABC"
                "last_name": "ACDD"
        }
     }
  }
```

What I want:

```
 {
    "don_info":{
        "st_contacts":{
            "don_contact":{
                "first_name":"Test1",
                "last_name":"Test2"
            },
            "correspondence_contact":{
                "first_name":"ABC",
                "last_name":"ACDD"
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Either there is something wrong with your PHP installation (`json_encode()` should never return invalid JSON) or you are not actually getting that output from the function. Also worth nothing that neither snippet you shared with us is valid JSON.

Comment: I cannot replicate the problem with the code you have provided. What version of PHP are you using?

Comment: There seems to be a few errors in the script. For example your `submission` array is not closing on the correct array level. After I fixed your errors, my `json_encode` worked just fine

Comment: @Diogo,  which result are you getting with your json... is it same as my expected result?

Comment: I am getting this: `{"don_info":{"st_contacts":{"don_contact":{"first_name":"Test 1st name","last_name":"Test surname"},"correspondence_contact":{"first_name":"Test 1st name","last_name":"Test surname"}}}}`. Obviously I removed the object for string test as I do not have access to your objects or their origin

Comment: @diogo , which object did you removed? "I removed the object for string test"

Comment: You are using the `$donor->first_name` for example. Because I do not have access to said object, I replaced those for a `Test` string.
If you prefer I can add the code changes to the answer to be easier for you to visualise

Comment: can you show me what is your Test string?

Comment: My test string is what my json is pointing out in its fields where it should be where you object was providing a result. `"first_name":"Test 1st name"` where `Test 1st name` was your `$donor->first_name`

Comment: Your code works exactly as expected. https://3v4l.org/vaDaX